# Rebuilding a jQuery slick carousel after AJAX call; "unslick" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slick.js

I am using the slick carousel plug-in defined here:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

My carousel resides within content that is refreshed by an AJAX call. When the call returns, I attempt this within the .complete method, after I have replaced the content:

```
$('.thumbnails')
.slick('unslick')
.slick({ ... });
```

where "..." is the same set of parameters used to build the original carousel.

The problem is that slick.js is throwing an error:

```
TypeError: _[i].slick is undefined
ret = _[i].slick[opt].apply(_[i].slick, args);
```

where "opt" is apparently "unslick", at least according to my debug attempts.

If I omit the "unslick" method, then I don't get an error message, but my carousel appears with a full extra set of images; they are all squashed together and overlay one another, until I navigate to a new slide, and then things straighten themselves out ... but I really don't want the old images, just the new ones in the AJAX content.

Comment: Did you try doing it on 2 lines?
$('.thumbnails').slick('unslick');
$('.thumbnails').slick({ ... });

Comment: Also, I feel like you might be better off using the add/remove functions.

Comment: The error occurs on the .slick('unslick') call; it doesn't seem to matter if it occurs on its own line. (It's incurring the error before the follow-up .slick({}) call; I'd be tremendously surprised if the author didn't follow the jQuery convention of returning the object you're acting on!)

Comment: Also, I looked at removing items, but was discouraged, as the method only works on an item at a time, and you must know the index. What I need is "remove-all" so I can tear them all out at one swoop.

Comment: @Murwiz You should remove the existing slides from slick. And then add new ones that will get you started. Also post a Fiddle so that we could help  more.

Comment: @Murwiz Share the html part as well. If you are adding images inside divs then you might just change the source of images and remove the excess divs from DOM and then call slick init.